# Playing ping pong with queries

Tags: postgresql

I have a setup for 2 tables which is rather curious.

Table A:
it has multiple columns, but is basically a collection of information.
Say:

```
------------------------------------
my_id| name | address | lat | long
```

Table B is a long list of relationshisp between elements of table A:
For example:

```
------------------
my_id | parent_id
```

What I want to do is the following:

For any A.my_id, get the list of the B.my_id which have A.my_id as B.parent_id (there is also the case in which there's noone) and then:

get, for each element in this list (we just got), lats and longs from table A for these ids and create an 2 array out of them.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am rather new to SQL and while I managed up 'til now, this really baffles me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT results.lat, results.long 
FROM a 
JOIN b 
    ON b.parent_id=a.my_id 
JOIN a AS results 
    ON results.my_id=b.my_id
WHERE a.my_id = 'the one I'm looking for'
```

Ignoring the selected columns for a minute, the query will give you rows from table A that match the particular ID you're looking for (see the where clause), joined with rows from B that have the same parent ID as the ID you're looking for, joined with table A again, this time rows that have an ID that matches the ID in B.

If your tables look like this:

```
TABLE A
my_id| name | address | lat | long
  1    ABC    1234      10     20
  2    DEF    5678      15     19
  3    GHI    9101      17     21
  4    JKL    1121      18     18
 ...

TABLE B
my_id|parent_id
  1      4
  3      4
 ...
```

If you do this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM a 
JOIN b 
    ON b.parent_id=a.my_id 
JOIN a AS results 
    ON results.my_id=b.my_id
WHERE a.my_id = 4
```

You should get these results:

```
a.my_id | a.name | a.address | a.lat | a.long | b.my_id | b.parent_id | results.my_id | results.name | results.address | results.lat | results.long
   4       JKL       1121       18       18        1          4             1             ABC                   1234           10             20
   4       JKL       1121       18       18        3          4             3             GHI                   9101           17             21
```

From there we just change the columns in the `SELECT` to affect what the results look like.

The trick here is using the same table (A) in two places in the `JOIN`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, it's not clear to me how I do the aggregate... could please explain the query, the logic and how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Edited my response to include an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I resolved the issue by generalizing your answer and getting it to work. My understanding of it is that each time I need to take data (do a ping or a pong) I need to join on what I need.